# Python Pandas | Find maximum value only from a specific part of a column

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have been trying to do this. Pandas max() would find the maximum value from the entire column. What I need is:

My input csv file:

```
Id  Param1          Param2              Val1
1  -5.00138282776   2.04990620034e-08   1.738e-05
1  -4.80147838593   2.01516989762e-08   1.628e-05
1  -4.60159301758   1.98263165885e-08   1.671e-05
1  -4.40133094788   1.94918392538e-08   1.576e-05
1  -4.20143127441   1.91767686175e-08   
2  -5.00141859055   6.88369405921e-09   5.512e-06
2  -4.80152130126   6.77335965093e-09   5.964e-06
2  -4.60163593292   6.65415056389e-09
3  -5.00138044357   1.16316911658e-08   4.008e-06
3  -4.80148792267   1.15515588206e-08   7.347e-06
3  -4.60160970681   1.14048361866e-08   8.446e-06
3  -4.40137386322   1.12357021465e-08
```

Output needed:

```
Id  Param1          Param2              Val1        Max_Val1_for_each_Id
1  -5.00138282776   2.04990620034e-08   1.738e-05   1.738e-05
1  -4.80147838593   2.01516989762e-08   1.628e-05
1  -4.60159301758   1.98263165885e-08   1.671e-05
1  -4.40133094788   1.94918392538e-08   1.576e-05
1  -4.20143127441   1.91767686175e-08   
2  -5.00141859055   6.88369405921e-09   5.512e-06   5.964e-06
2  -4.80152130126   6.77335965093e-09   5.964e-06
2  -4.60163593292   6.65415056389e-09
3  -5.00138044357   1.16316911658e-08   4.008e-06   8.446e-06
3  -4.80148792267   1.15515588206e-08   7.347e-06
3  -4.60160970681   1.14048361866e-08   8.446e-06
3  -4.40137386322   1.12357021465e-08
```

I am not sure how to select/group values from Val1 column with the same Id and then find their maximum value. Also, I have some blanks in the Val1 column, rendering its datatype as object. I don't know how to go about this. Any help would be most welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for new column of `max` values per group:

```
df['Max_Val1_for_each_Id'] = df.groupby('Id')['Val1'].transform('max')
print (df)
    Id    Param1        Param2      Val1  Max_Val1_for_each_Id
0    1 -5.001383  2.049906e-08  0.000017              0.000017
1    1 -4.801478  2.015170e-08  0.000016              0.000017
2    1 -4.601593  1.982632e-08  0.000017              0.000017
3    1 -4.401331  1.949184e-08  0.000016              0.000017
4    1 -4.201431  1.917677e-08       NaN              0.000017
5    2 -5.001419  6.883694e-09  0.000006              0.000006
6    2 -4.801521  6.773360e-09  0.000006              0.000006
7    2 -4.601636  6.654151e-09       NaN              0.000006
8    3 -5.001380  1.163169e-08  0.000004              0.000008
9    3 -4.801488  1.155156e-08  0.000007              0.000008
10   3 -4.601610  1.140484e-08  0.000008              0.000008
11   3 -4.401374  1.123570e-08       NaN              0.000008
```

And then if need only first value add [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html) with mask created by [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with `~` for invert mask:

```
df['Max_Val1_for_each_Id'] = df['Max_Val1_for_each_Id'].where(~df['Id'].duplicated())
print (df)
    Id    Param1        Param2      Val1  Max_Val1_for_each_Id
0    1 -5.001383  2.049906e-08  0.000017              0.000017
1    1 -4.801478  2.015170e-08  0.000016                   NaN
2    1 -4.601593  1.982632e-08  0.000017                   NaN
3    1 -4.401331  1.949184e-08  0.000016                   NaN
4    1 -4.201431  1.917677e-08       NaN                   NaN
5    2 -5.001419  6.883694e-09  0.000006              0.000006
6    2 -4.801521  6.773360e-09  0.000006                   NaN
7    2 -4.601636  6.654151e-09       NaN                   NaN
8    3 -5.001380  1.163169e-08  0.000004              0.000008
9    3 -4.801488  1.155156e-08  0.000007                   NaN
10   3 -4.601610  1.140484e-08  0.000008                   NaN
11   3 -4.401374  1.123570e-08       NaN                   NaN
```

EDIT:

If `Val1` have no `NaN` values and solution above raise error:

> TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'

first step is convert non numeric to `NaN`s:

```
df['Val1'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Val1'], errors='coerce')
df['Max_Val1_for_each_Id'] = df.groupby('Id')['Val1'].transform('max')
df['Max_Val1_for_each_Id'] = df['Max_Val1_for_each_Id'].where(~df['Id'].duplicated())
```

Answer (score 1):

Interesting way with Numpy

```
f, u = pd.factorize(df.Id)
out = np.zeros(len(u))
whr = np.ones(len(u), np.int64) * len(f)

mask = np.isnan(df.Val1)

np.maximum.at(out, f[~mask], df.Val1[~mask])
np.minimum.at(whr, f, np.arange(len(f)))

df.assign(Max_Val1_for_each_Id=pd.Series(out, df.index[whr]))

    Id    Param1        Param2      Val1  Max_Val1_for_each_Id
0    1 -5.001383  2.049906e-08  0.000017              0.000017
1    1 -4.801478  2.015170e-08  0.000016                   NaN
2    1 -4.601593  1.982632e-08  0.000017                   NaN
3    1 -4.401331  1.949184e-08  0.000016                   NaN
4    1 -4.201431  1.917677e-08       NaN                   NaN
5    2 -5.001419  6.883694e-09  0.000006              0.000006
6    2 -4.801521  6.773360e-09  0.000006                   NaN
7    2 -4.601636  6.654151e-09       NaN                   NaN
8    3 -5.001380  1.163169e-08  0.000004              0.000008
9    3 -4.801488  1.155156e-08  0.000007                   NaN
10   3 -4.601610  1.140484e-08  0.000008                   NaN
11   3 -4.401374  1.123570e-08       NaN                   NaN
```